# How to infinitely repeat animation through delay

Tags: java, animation

I'm trying to achieve an effect where my recyclerview items will shake slightly at some intervals.

I have animation shake:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <rotate
        android:duration="30"
        android:fromDegrees="-2"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="20"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:toDegrees="2" />
</set>
```

This animation i use for item recyclerview. I want so my items be shake every 5 second.

My method start animate in recyclerviewAdapter:

```
private void setAnimation(View viewToAnimate, int position)
{
    if (position > lastPosition)
    {
        Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.shake_animation);
        viewToAnimate.startAnimation(shake);
        lastPosition = position;
    }
}
```

Right now, my animation runs exactly once at the very beginning. That is, 20 repetitions are performed (repeatCount="20"), but only once. And I want it to repeat endlessly, but with pauses.

That is, how to set the `duration` not for each movement of the animation, but for the entire animation?
I get so that `duration` just slows down the animation itself. And I need to repeat it with a pause between each iteration.

I've been reading about `setAdapter` but I've never been able to apply it to my animation

any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Guys: the solution turned out to be very simple. I'm a total noob)

Just use Handler:

```
private void setAnimation(View viewToAnimate, int position)
{
    if (position > lastPosition)
    {

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.shake_animation);
                viewToAnimate.startAnimation(shake);
                handler.postDelayed(this, 6000);
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(r, 5000);
        lastPosition = position;
    }
}
```